# PMD: DU - Anomaly: A recently defined variable is undefined.... But it is

Tags: java, pmd, static-code-analysis

The definition of the DU Anomaly says:

> DU - Anomaly: A recently defined variable is undefined. These
>   anomalies may appear in normal source text.

But that seems to be false for the following code, although the `DU - Anomaly` shows up:

```
private void aFancyMethod(final List<SomeObject> resultList, int maxLevel)
{
    int newMaxLevel;
    if (maxLevel < 1)
    {
        newMaxLevel = 1; // DU - Anomaly here
    } else
    {
        newMaxLevel = maxLevel; // DU - Anomaly here
    } 

    for (SomeObject[] revArray : resultList)
    {
        someOtherMethodCall(revArray, currentLevel, newMaxLevel);
    } 
}
```

What is the reason the `DU - Anomaly` is showing up?

Comment: This definitely looks like a False Positive. Please check to be using the latest PMD version (at this moment, 5.5.4), and if it still reports that, please submit an issue report on PMD's Github: https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues